# Disable or checked previously selected items of checkboxlist?

Tags: asp.net

i want to disable or checkd previously  selected items. the selected item were saved in database as userid_checkbox iteams.i  need to get selected items by a user. if user id is 10 and selected item is 2  then it will save in database 10_2. so  i  need to  split it to  get the second item number  and use loop  to disable the selected items. i  have  written as  below

```
        int user_id = Convert.ToInt16(Session["user_id"]);
        ward w = new ward();
        using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
        {
            List<string> bednum = (from j in db.wards where w.user_id == user_id select j.wbedno).ToList();
             foreach (var bed in bednum)
             {
                 string vals = bed.Split('_')[1];
                 cbList = (CheckBoxList)pnlControls.FindControl(vals);
                 //  cbList.Items.Add(new ListItem(vals));


                 var query = from listItem in cbList.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                             //   join item in bednum  on
                             where listItem.Value == bed
                             select listItem;

                 //   var query =  from l  in cbList.Items
                 foreach (ListItem listItem in query)
                     listItem.Selected = true;

             }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
int user_id = Convert.ToInt16(Session["user_id"]);
CheckBoxList cbList = (CheckBoxList)pnlControls.FindControl("MyCheckBoxListID");
ward w = new ward();//Guessing ward is a class?

using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
    List<string> bednum = (from j in db.wards where w.user_id == user_id select j.wbedno).ToList();
    foreach (var bed in bednum)
    {
        string vals = bed.Split('_')[1];
        ListItem listItem = cbList.Items.FindByValue(vals);
        if (listItem != null) listItem.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply . how i can i use find control to catch dynamically created checkboxlist like that  state in below .   for (int i = 0; i < bedNo; i++)
        {
            cbList.ID = Convert.ToString  (i);
            cbList.Items.Add(new ListItem( (i + 1).ToString(), (i + 1).ToString()));
          

        }  pnlControls.Controls.Add(cbList);

Comment: If you add a control dynamically to another container control as a child, it will not be available at the next post back in the same containers child controls collection. So what you must do is create the same control again, assign its properties and add to child controls collection again.

Comment: yep,i add the control in the same page in page load . i need to catch the cbList that create and disable those . like that if i set cbList.ID = "cb" +i; pnlControls.Controls.Add(cbList). what will be the fincontrol CheckBoxList cbList = (CheckBoxList)pnlControls.FindControl("cb" +i);   ???